Why doesn't current flow stop in LC oscillation?
Why doesn't current flow stop in a LC circuit? It is supposed to stop when the magnitude of emf developed across capacitor is the same as the inductor, right?

It stops but then it starts again... why does a pendulum having stopped at one end comes back again? There is force on it. At the moment the cap becomes fully charged the current is zero but then the electrostatic force on the charges is maximum and the current restarts in the opposite direction.

The mechanical analogy of an LC-circuit is a mass-spring (m[1/k]-)system. So, as others have said, although the current i=0 [only momentarily], (di/dt) is not zero.

Please include a schematic of the oscillator you are considering. If the inductor and capacitor are in parallel, then the voltages across them are always equal, but that doesn't mean that the current stops.

The current does periodically become zero in an $LC$ circuit. However, since the current obeys a sinusoidal oscillation with respect to time, its time-derivative would be a cosinusoidal function - i.e. 90 degrees out of phase.
That means when the current is zero, the rate of change of current is not zero - its magnitude is actually maximised. That means the current cannot remain at zero.
A physical picture of what is going on is given in Why do Capacitor Inductor circuits Oscillate instead of reaching equilibrium?
